# Can I browse Silverlight sites on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: internet-explorer

I am using the HTC Radar Windows 7.5 based phone. I thought a specialty of Windows phones is that they are silverlight based phone.

Why am I redirected to the "Install Silverlight page" when I try to view a Silverlight plugin in IE?. The example site which tried was [Azure Management portal](http://windows.azure.com).

Comment: What page is the Silverlight on? I don't see it. Also, it's http://windowsazure.com and not http://windows.azure.com.

Comment: @tom, the site he mentioned is the management portal. If you have an account you will be able to see it :)

Comment: Of course, you could petition them to develop a Windows Phone app (if there isn't one already), as the migration path from Silverlight to Windows Phone isn't as major as going from another technology

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Silverlight and Silverlight for Windows Phone are different, note that the former is meant to be ran on PC while the latter is meant to be ran on a Windows Phone. Note that the IE browser on the Windows Phone does not have an embedded Silverlight plugin. Only your phone itself can run Silverlight applications.

Answer (score 5):

Windows phone isn't a "Silverlight phone", and just like you can't view Flash, you also can't view Silverlight.

What you are thinking about is that apps can be built using Silverlight. Sorry, but websites that use Silverlight aren't an option :(

If you are trying to manage Azure subscriptions from you phone, search the marketplace. I found a few that let you do it. One such is http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=e0e4066b-55f8-4c04-9d3b-8b28f3224881. I haven't used it yet, so I can't speak to how awesome, or terrible it is.